# Linq query to get number of companies for each IP

Tags: c#, linq

I have to two list.

```
        var companies = new List <CompanyData> {
            new Data {Company= "company1", Location= "location1"},
            new Data {Company= "company2", Location= "location1"},
            new Data {Company= "company1", Location= "location2"},
            new Data {Company= "company3", Location= "location1"},
            new Data {Company= "company2", Location= "location2"},
            new Data {Company= "company1", Location= "location3"},
            new Data {Company= "company1", Location= "location4"}
        };

        var locations= new List<LocationData> {
            new Data {IP= "ip1", Location= "location1"},
            new Data {IP= "ip1", Location= "location2"},
            new Data {IP= "ip2", Location= "location3"},
            new Data {IP= "ip3", Location= "location4"},
        };
```

I wanted to list of companies on each IP location. how to get through LINQ ?

Expect result

```
var result = new SortedList<string,List<string>>()
                  {"ip1", new List<string>{"company1","company2",..}}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *Welcome to stackoverflow!* This site helps solving issues with your code. *You should post your code here when you have results which are different from expected, or when you get an error.* You also should describe what results you have and what is expected and/or provide error details. After that community will help you to solve issues and (sometimes) it'll give you some guidance. That is how stackoverflow works. As you can see, your question doesn't have all appropriate information. Please **edit** your question and add code with other required information if you want to get some help.

Comment: Also don't use same data structure for completely different data. Create two classes with appropriate properties `Company { Name, Location }` and `Location { IP, Name }`

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to adapt this to your needs:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var companies = new List<Company> 
                            {new Company {Name = "company1", Location = "location1"},
                             new Company {Name = "company2", Location = "location1"},
                             new Company {Name = "company1", Location = "location2"},
                             new Company {Name = "company3", Location = "location1"},
                             new Company {Name = "company2", Location = "location2"},
                             new Company {Name = "company1", Location = "location3"},
                             new Company {Name = "company1", Location = "location4"}};

        var locations = new List<IP>
                            {new IP {Name = "ip1", Location = "location1"},
                             new IP {Name = "ip1", Location = "location2"},
                             new IP {Name = "ip2", Location = "location3"},
                             new IP {Name = "ip3", Location = "location4"}};

        var query = locations.Join(companies, 
                                   ip => ip.Location, 
                                   c => c.Location, 
                                   (ip, c) => new JoinResult() { IP = ip, 
                                                                 Company = c });

        foreach (var result in query)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("IP: {0} - {1}, Company: {2}", 
                              result.IP.Name, 
                              result.IP.Location, 
                              result.Company.Name);
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public class Company
    {
        public string Name;
        public string Location;
    }

    public class IP
    {
        public string Name;
        public string Location;
    }

    public class JoinResult
    {
        public Company Company;
        public IP IP;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
IP: ip1 - location1, Company: company1
IP: ip1 - location1, Company: company2
IP: ip1 - location1, Company: company3
IP: ip1 - location2, Company: company1
IP: ip1 - location2, Company: company2
IP: ip2 - location3, Company: company1
IP: ip3 - location4, Company: company1
```

Answer (score 0):

Following on from test's above solution, you can use Group in LINQ to group the companies by IP:

```
void Main()
{
    var companies = new List<Company>
                            {new Company {Name = "company1", Location = "location1"},
                             new Company {Name = "company2", Location = "location1"},
                             new Company {Name = "company1", Location = "location2"},
                             new Company {Name = "company3", Location = "location1"},
                             new Company {Name = "company2", Location = "location2"},
                             new Company {Name = "company1", Location = "location3"},
                             new Company {Name = "company1", Location = "location4"}};

    var locations = new List<IP>
                            {new IP {Name = "ip1", Location = "location1"},
                             new IP {Name = "ip1", Location = "location2"},
                             new IP {Name = "ip2", Location = "location3"},
                             new IP {Name = "ip3", Location = "location4"}};

    var query = locations.Join(companies,
                               ip => ip.Location,
                               c => c.Location,
                               (ip, c) => new JoinResult()
                               {
                                   IP = ip,
                                   Company = c
                               });

    var companiesByIp = query.GroupBy(b => b.IP.Name);

    foreach (var ip in companiesByIp)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("IP: {0}, {1} companies", ip.Key, ip.Count()));
    }

}

public class Company
{
    public string Name;
    public string Location;
}

public class IP
{
    public string Name;
    public string Location;
}

public class JoinResult
{
    public Company Company;
    public IP IP;
}
```

This would output the following:

```
IP: ip1, 5 companies
IP: ip2, 1 companies
IP: ip3, 1 companies
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I wanted the same result